# How to give a SectionList a flexDirection of 'row' in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview, react-native-sectionlist

I would like to get a SectionList with a flexDirection of row working, this is the code I have atm:

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
// Amount of posters in a row
const columns = 3;

class Posters extends Component {
  _renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() => this._getMovieInfo(item.hasPerformances[0].filmId)}
        key={index}
      >
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.posterUrl }} style={styles.image} />
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.title} numberOfLines={1}>{item.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  _getMovieInfo(url) {
    this.props.movieDataChanged(url);
    this.props.popupChanged(true);
  }

  _renderSections(array) {
    return (
      <SectionList
        style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 'row' }}
        renderItem={this._renderItems}
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { name } }) => (
          <View style={{ width, maringBottom: 8 }}>
            <Text style={styles.releaseStyle}>{name}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        sections={array}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
        {
          this.props.posterData
            ? this._renderSections(this.props.posterData)
            : <View style={styles.loadingStyle}><ActivityIndicator size="small" color={colors.typography} /></View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { movieDataChanged, popupChanged })(Posters);
```

it works and looks like this[image: SectionList]

however I would like to display the covers next to each other like in a grid. I got this working bevor with a map method however I would like to change this because of performance issues an lazy loading, can someone help pls ?

Comment: SectionList inherits all ScrollView props so you can add `horizontal` as a prop: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#horizontal

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to get the scroll view horizontally, I would like to get 3 posters next to each and underneath those posters the next in line, but in the end I would like to scroll vertically.

Comment: you could group your `sections` array into a multidimensional array and return a flex row with 3 touchables, so instead of `[item, item, item, item, item, item]` you would pass in `[ [item, item, item], [item, item, item] ]`

Comment: well then I can't have a header for each section I guess, I have applied this: contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', }} to the SectionList and now it's working as expected however its showing me the following warning in the console: "Warning: `flexWrap: `wrap`` is not supported with the `VirtualizedList` components.Consider using `numColumns` with `FlatList` instead" do you know how serious those messages are ?

Comment: you could still have a header but you would have to change your render logic. Regardless, if you're getting the behavior you want then it's probably fine as long as it doesn't say "deprecated". If it says the feature is deprecated that means that your component will break on a future release as they plan to remove that feature. Weird that it says unsupported but you're getting the behavior you want, I would just roll with it

Answer (score -2):

You can add this to `<SectionList>`

```
contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
          }}
```